# Insert and update 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing an insert and update 2 table. When I insert, I want newly created Id to update new table.

```
insert into Event(EventName, EventManager, EventManagerShortName, EventTicketId) Values(@eventname, (select ManagerShortName From Manager where ManagerID = @managerid), @eventticketid)
```

I can do this:

```
set @eventId = select Eventid from Event where EventTicketId = @eventticketid

update ScheduledEvents set EventID = @eventid, IsPaymentCompleted = true,  IsCancelled = false where ScheduledDate = @scheduleddate
```

Is there a better way of doing this then using a variable to get the newly created Id every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

This function returns the last created identity value from the current session.

```
insert into Event
(EventName, EventManager, EventManagerShortName, EventTicketId)
Values
(@eventname, (select top 1 ManagerShortName From Manager where ManagerID = @managerid), @eventticketid)


set @eventId = scope_identity() --must immediately follow the above line

update ScheduledEvents 
set EventID = @eventid
, IsPaymentCompleted = true
,  IsCancelled = false 
where ScheduledDate = @scheduleddate
```